# Books on time series and sequence classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, books

Though I have been using traditional machine learning algorithms (Regression and Classification) , I have no experience of using Time series and would like to understand what is time series and different approaches(ex:ARIMA,SARIMA,SARIMAX, LSTM etc) used for time series analysis. I also see that people use LSTM's/RNN for time series/sequence classification. Can you people recommend me a book that discusses the above algorithms and how Time series is different from sequence classification etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous topics that you've mentioned but I will suggest those which I've read and are helpful.

For hidden markov models and markov processes I suggest reading **Pattern Classification** by *Richard O. Duda*. You can also take a look at **Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning** by *Christopher Bishop*. For better understanding Markov processes and their behaviour, you can also take the course stochastic process which is also known as *random process*. I suggest taking that course before reading any book, because you may need some help if you're not very familiar to the concepts.

For `LSTMs`, I highly suggest taking a look at the fifth course of deep learning on coursera by pr. *Andrew Ng*. If you do their homework you can realise how the inner operations exactly work and you'll have a very deep understanding of time series and what their nature is. After that, you can take a look at the *Deep Learning* book by *Ian Goodfellow*.

Comment: Hi, I know its a bit late. thanks for the response. Upvoted